# Admin toolbar is not showing when i am logged in in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I checked in my theme(Used divi builder) header.php  and there was wp_head and in footer.php there was php wp_footer
In my user profile it is cheked the "Show Toolbar when viewing site".It is a site that i build two years ago and i tryed even updating theme and plugins.But still it isnt showing.Does any one have another idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The admin toolbar can be de- and activated if you edit the user account in the backend, as you already tried.

It can be set to not being displayed in the style.css of your theme, look for the id:

#wpadminbar

Or it can be disabled in the functions.php of your theme, look for something like:

add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

There can also be a membership setting, that disables the admin bar if the user has a certain user role. You can try another user or other user role and check if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The problem was one missing plugin called LiteSpeed Cache.After instaling the toolbar was shown.

Comment: That the plugin was missing cannot be the problem. If it was installed, maybe the plugin cached the page version without the toolbar. But installing it can not have solved this problem. Did you change anything else? You could not mind, because it's working now, but installing the plugin did not solve this issue, i'm sure.

Comment: If i remove the plugin i cant see toolbar.But actually i just noticed that it wasnt the only problem.I couldnt save changes even from backend. Dont now if it is important but i delete all files from server and upload an backup.In the bacup it wasnt the plugin.But i think the plugin has changed something in wp_config.

Comment: The plugin should not do changes to your wp_config.php. But it can hook into some functionality. Have you tried using my code in your themes functions.php with the "add_filter" and setting the "__return_true", so the value is true and the admin tool bar is enabled? I would recommend not to use a plugin, that is causing problems on your website, especially if it is only for caching and is not related to your problem.